# Unit Testing inList in Grails 2.4.x

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Before grails 2.4.x unit testing using `@Mock()`ed domain classes was working fine. In 2.4.x search with inList never returns results - using criteria, dynamic finders nor where clauses. It works if we use `HibernateTestMixin`. Is inList not supported anymore in unit testing or this is a bug?

droggo

Comment: Seeing the very same behaviour! Did you find a valid workaround?

Comment: As written in question, we moved to: HibernateTestMixin